# Exposing WCF Service over different methods

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

So we have recently moved much of our business logic into a service layer, which has led us to refactor the services we have exposed as API services. I consider myself experienced enough with WCF, but of course there is always more learning to be done. What I am interested in finding out, is not really something I can find in a book?

If we have a service **ReturnService** that we want to expose, but we want to expose it over SOAP and over REST, what is the best practice for doing this? Until now, I have always just created two implementations and interfaces, which goes against my preaching to use a single interface for multiple implementations.

I am not sure how I would use one interface for both implementations being that I need to specify the service specific information on the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can not use single Service Contract for both. Instead you can have two Service Contracts and implement both in single class.

Please read this [article](http://debugmode.net/2011/12/22/how-to-enable-rest-and-soap-both-on-the-same-wcf-service/) will help you.

This article is a step by step on doing exactly what you are asking about, exposing both REST and SOAP.  The article exposes the REST in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks Peter for suggestion. I will edit my post with essential setps with code.